# Catamorphisms for Church-encoded lists

Tags: haskell, recursion, church-encoding, catamorphism, recursion-schemes

I want to be able to use `cata` from `recursion-schemes` package for lists in Church encoding.

```
type ListC a = forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b
```

I used a second rank type for convenience, but I don't care. Feel free to add a `newtype`, use GADTs, etc. if you feel it is necessary.

The idea of Church encoding is widely known and simple:

```
three :: a -> a -> a -> List1 a 
three a b c = \cons nil -> cons a $ cons b $ cons c nil
```

Basically "abstract unspecified" `cons` and `nil` are used instead of "normal" constructors. I believe everything can be encoded this way (`Maybe`, trees, etc.).

It's easy to show that `List1` is indeed isomorphic to normal lists:

```
toList :: List1 a -> [a]
toList f = f (:) []

fromList :: [a] -> List1 a
fromList l = \cons nil -> foldr cons nil l
```

So its base functor is the same as of lists, and it should be possible to implement `project` for it and use the machinery from `recursion-schemes`.

But I couldn't, so my question is "how do I do that?". For normal lists, I can just pattern match:

```
decons :: [a] -> ListF a [a]
decons [] = Nil
decons (x:xs) = Cons x xs
```

Since I cannot pattern-match on functions, I have to use a fold to deconstruct the list. I could write a fold-based `project` for normal lists:

```
decons2 :: [a] -> ListF a [a]
decons2 = foldr f Nil
  where f h Nil = Cons h []
        f h (Cons hh t) = Cons h $ hh : t
```

However I failed to adapt it for Church-encoded lists:

```
-- decons3 :: ListC a -> ListF a (ListC a)
decons3 ff = ff f Nil
  where f h Nil = Cons h $ \cons nil -> nil
        f h (Cons hh t) = Cons h $ \cons nil -> cons hh (t cons nil)
```

`cata` has the following signature:

```
cata :: Recursive t => (Base t a -> a) -> t -> a
```

To use it with my lists, I need:

1. To declare the base functor type for the list using `type family instance Base (ListC a) = ListF a`
2. To implement `instance Recursive (List a) where project = ...`

I fail at both steps.

Comment: What is your failure? I've tried this (adding `newtype` for convenience) and it works fine.

Comment: The `newtype` turned out to be essential and not merely a convenience. The code works now.

Comment: It is in fact true that any algebraic data type has a church encoding.

Comment: Yep. I even tried to Church-encode the base functor: http://nponeccop.livejournal.com/454146.html

Answer (score 4):

The `newtype` wrapper turned out to be the crucial step I missed. Here is the code along with a sample catamorphism from `recursion-schemes`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase, Rank2Types, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable

newtype ListC a = ListC { foldListC :: forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b }

type instance Base (ListC a) = ListF a

cons :: a -> ListC a -> ListC a
cons x (ListC xs) = ListC $ \cons' nil' -> x `cons'` xs cons' nil'
nil :: ListC a
nil = ListC $ \cons' nil' -> nil'

toList :: ListC a -> [a]
toList f = foldListC f (:) []
fromList :: [a] -> ListC a
fromList l = foldr cons nil l

instance Recursive (ListC a) where
  project xs = foldListC xs f Nil
    where f x Nil = Cons x nil
          f x (Cons tx xs) = Cons x $ tx `cons` xs

len = cata $ \case Nil -> 0
                   Cons _ l -> l + 1
```